# Is there a way to set parameters for the Java VM when using a Snakemake wrapper?

Tags: snakemake, picard

When using tools like `picard` or `fgbio` through snakemake wrappers, I keep running into out-of-memory issues. At the moment I resort to direct `shell` calls, which allow me to set the VMs memory. I would prefer to pass these parameters to the wrapped tools. Is there a way, maybe through the `resources` directive, passing something like `mem_mb=10000`? I tried, but have not gotten it to work yet.

Answer (score 2):

According to wrapper sources (https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/src/bd3178f4b82b1856370bb48c8bdbb1932ace6a19/bio/picard/markduplicates/wrapper.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), it uses cmdline:

```py
from snakemake.shell import shell


shell("picard MarkDuplicates {snakemake.params} INPUT={snakemake.input} "
      "OUTPUT={snakemake.output.bam} METRICS_FILE={snakemake.output.metrics} "
      "&> {snakemake.log}")
```

So you could pass any options using `params: "smth"` section.

If you check `picard` excecutable script sources:

```sh
 cat `which picard`
```

You will find:

```sh
...
pass_args=""
for arg in "$@"; do
    case $arg in
        '-D'*)
            jvm_prop_opts="$jvm_prop_opts $arg"
            ;;
        '-XX'*)
            jvm_prop_opts="$jvm_prop_opts $arg"
            ;;
         '-Xm'*)
            jvm_mem_opts="$jvm_mem_opts $arg"
            ;;
         *)
            if [[ ${pass_args} == '' ]] #needed to avoid preceeding space on first arg e.g. ' MarkDuplicates'
            then 
                pass_args="$arg" 
            else
                pass_args="$pass_args \"$arg\"" #quotes later arguments to avoid problem with ()s in MarkDuplicates regex arg
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done
...
```

So I assume this should work:

```py
rule markdups:
    input:
        "in.bam",
    output:
        bam = "out.bam",
        metrics = "metrics.tmp",
    params:
        "-Xmx10000m"
    wrapper:
        "0.31.0/bio/picard/markduplicates"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the wrapper directive but looking for example at [markduplicates/wrapper.py](http://picard/markduplicates/wrapper.py) the shell command is `picard MarkDuplicates {snakemake.params} ...`. So maybe using the `params` slot works?

```
rule markdups:
    input:
        'in.bam',
    output:
        bam= 'out.bam',
        metrics= 'metrics.tmp',
    params:
        mem= "-Xmx4g",
    wrapper:
        "0.31.0/bio/picard/markduplicates"
```

picard should understand that `-Xmx...` is a java parameter.